# Android: testing an app directly from the Google Play

Tags: android

I'd like to publish an app for Android, but also to test it before then. Is it possible to test it directly on a hardware device without installing the development environment? For the lazy kind of testers.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you mean installing an .apk on a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an installer app (I use [Rhythm Software's Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhythm.hexise.inst)) then you can distribute an APK file to any device (mail it, dropbox, ftp, etc.) and then install it without having to connect to a development environment.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable unknown sources under security in your devices settings and sideload the app, if you don't want to use the adb(you could just hook it up to your Computer, enable USB debugging and install the apk on your device)